# In Bohmian mechanics, it the uncertainty due to non-locality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, bohmian-mechanics

In the pilot-wave interpretation of quantum mechanics, each particle is driven by the pilot wave on the universal configuration space, and therefore its trajectory is determined nonlocally, and depends on the configuration of all other particles.

If this is so, we shouldn't be able to predict the trajectory of a particle even by having its exact initial position and its 3D wavefunction we calculate from the Schrodinger's equation, because we don't have the universal wavefunction. Of course, it is expected that the non-local effects would AVERAGE to zero, but certainly they are not instantaneously zero at a moment. So is this where the Born rule uncertainty in Bohmian mechanics comes from, that the particle makes some unpredictable movements caused by the hidden universal wavefunction?

Comment: No, that's not where the uncertainty in Bohmian mechanics comes from. It comes from the quantum equilibrium assumption. If you are accounting for other particles, you need to apply that assumption to their joint pilot wave -- each particle does not have an individual pilot wave.

Comment: [Ditto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory#Heisenberg's_uncertainty_principle).

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks! I think this also says what I meant, we can't know the trajectory because we can't know the wavefunction. But I think the random shape of the trajectory is due to non-local effects caused by the universal wavefunction. We can know the marginal wavefunction of the particle from the 3D schrodinger equation, and it doesn't give us information about random looking movements caused by the universal wavefunction. Am I right?

Comment: I don't understand the point to tell. Measurements of the trajectory affect the wavefunction pretty much as in standard QM, and its properties limit observability the same way. The particle is just a probe of the wavefunction. A good review of the subject should address your issues.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/161515/in-bohmian-mechanics-how-does-the-particles-position-affect-where-a-particle-i).