# In the pilot-wave theory, is the quantum potential moving electrons randomly inside atoms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, orbitals, born-rule, bohmian-mechanics

As we know, in the pilot-wave theory (Bohmian mechanics), particles are guided on certain trajectories by the wavefunction. Here ([In Bohmian mechanics, do electrons move inside an atom?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/477490/in-bohmian-mechanics-do-electrons-move-inside-an-atom?noredirect=1#comment1072369_477490)) I asked about the trajectories of electrons inside an atom. The wavefunction of an electron inside the atom is stationary, so the apparent contradiction in the pilot-wave theory is that the electron is not moving inside the atom, while we know it has a kinetic energy.

The solution to this problem is that in Bohmian mechanics, the electron's kinetic energy is transferred to its "quantum potential". Now my question is, does this mean that the electron is NOT stationary in the atom, but it is moving around the nucleus in a Bohmian way?

And also, Bohmian mechanics is nonlocal. The wavefunction of the electron might be stationary, but the electron is guided by the universal wavefunction, not merely its own wavefunction, and the universal wavefunction is not stationary. So the electron should be seemingly randomly moving inside the atom (the universal wavefunction can be any random thing), but having its kinetic energy stored in the quantum potential and its position distributed according to the Born rule, as the nonlocal effects would average to zero.

See https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0403034 as an illustration. Is this how the Bohmian model works for an electron inside an atom?